# 2D Array access violation on delete (Borland C++)

Tags: c++, g++, access-violation, borland-c++

I have the following code:

```
nErgebnisse = new unsigned int*[nInitialVecSize];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= nInitialVecSize; ++i )
{
  nErgebnisse[i] = new unsigned int[nMaxSektorMenge];
}

//do some stuff

for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= nInitialVecSize; ++i )
{
   delete[] nErgebnisse[i];
}
delete[] nErgebnisse;
```

It just allocates and deletes a 2D unsigned int array.
This code works fine with the current G++, but with my Borland Compiler at work I get an access violation on the first

```
delete[] nErgebnisse[0]
```

saying:

> access violation at 0x32b6f4e3: write of address 0xffffffff

What is the problem here?

Comment: I think it should be `i < nInitialVecSize`instead of `i <= nInitialVecSize`

Comment: @skylla - it does, as you have undefined behavior in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are creating an array but

```
nErgebnisse = new unsigned int*[nInitialVecSize];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= nInitialVecSize; ++i )
{
  nErgebnisse[i] = new unsigned int[nMaxSektorMenge];
}
```

when `i = nInitialVecSize` you are writing beyond the bounds of your array because you have `<=` in your for loop. Use this instead

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < nInitialVecSize; ++i )
```